# using ActiveXObject in Winforms web browser Control

Tags: c#, javascript, winforms, webbrowser-control, activexobject

I'm using JavaScript code in c# web browser object (winform).
from some reason I cannot use ActiveXObject...
the line:

```
var fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
```

doesn't work.

Answer (score 3):

The object in question is not marked Safe-For-Scripting because it exposes unsafe functionality to potentially untrusted content.

In order for such objects to run, you will need to attach a delegate security manager and return URL_POLICY_ALLOW for URLAction 0x1201.